# How to export CPU Usage of VM on Azure to Azure Storage

Tags: azure-storage, cpu-usage, azure-monitoring

I am new to Azure. I have a requirement to export CPU Uptime, Outage (if any) and CPU Utilization of VM to be exported to Azure Storage. Only this much is needed to be filtered out from all other already provided options. Can you guide me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referred to the suggestion mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/monitor)

[Azure VM Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-performance) and [Supported Metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported)

[Get Virtual Machine usage metrics using the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/metrics-vm-usage-rest)